# Multiple jQgrids in jQueryui Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am having an issue that I need help with.  I have 3 jQueryUI Tabs.  The first holds a grid of items.  The second holds a grid of Work Orders.  The third just fires an alert to verify the show function is working.  Problem is I have no grid on the second tab.  First one loads fine.  If I comment out the code for the first tab, the second grid shows up fine.  Third tab fires an alert every time.  I have a lightbox that i use to edit items on select which works fine.  Here's the relevant code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabs').tabs({
show: function(event, ui) {
    if(ui.index == 0)
    {
     jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
...
pager: '#pager1',
...
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});         
}
    else if(ui.index == 1)
    {
     $("#list").jqGrid({
...
pager: '#pager',
....
onSelectRow: function(id){ 
  if(id){ 
    alert(id);
     onclick=openbox('Edit Work Order', 1);
    ...

    else if(ui.index == 2)
    {
     alert('tab2');
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: You should modify your question and include more full code which can be used to reproduce your problem. One general problem in your code fragment: `jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({...});` and `$("#list").jqGrid({...});` should be called once and not on very tab select. It could be helpful to verify your javascript code for syntax errors in http://www.jslint.com/. The line `onclick=openbox('Edit Work Order', 1)` looks very strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably your problem exist because you used the HTML code

```
<div id="tabs-1">
   <table id="list1"><tr><td/></tr></table>
   <div id="pager1"/>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
   <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table>
   <div id="pager"/>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Bla bla</p>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div id="tabs-1">
   <table id="list1"><tr><td/></tr></table>
   <div id="pager1"></div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
   <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table>
   <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Bla bla</p>
</div>
```

I modified you code a little to the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var initGrids= [false,false];
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        show: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.index === 0 && initGrids[ui.index] === false) {
                jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
                    url: 'fillgrid.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    colNames: ['serial', 'type', 'origin', 'subtype', 'refreshdate'],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55 },
                        { name: 'type', index: 'type', width: 90 },
                        { name: 'origin', index: 'origin', width: 80, align: 'right' },
                        { name: 'subtype', index: 'subtype', width: 80, align: 'right' },
                        { name: 'refreshdate', index: 'refreshdate', width: 80, align: 'right' }
                    ],
                    pager: '#pager1',
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowlist: [10, 20, 30],
                    sortname: 'id', // NOT 'serial',
                    sortorder: 'desc',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: 'CPE Items',
                    width: 950
                });
                jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
                initGrids[ui.index] = true;
            }
            else if (ui.index === 1 && initGrids[ui.index] === false) {
                $("#list").jqGrid({
                    url: 'fillgridwo.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    colNames: ['Job Number', 'Date', 'System', 'Status', 'Technician', 'Timeframe'],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55 },
                        { name: 'Date', index: 'date', width: 90 },
                        { name: 'System', index: 'wsystem', width: 80, align: 'right' },
                        { name: 'Status', index: 'status', width: 80, align: 'right' },
                        { name: 'Technician', index: 'wname', width: 80, align: 'right' },
                        { name: 'Timeframe', index: 'time', width: 80, align: 'right' }
                    ],
                    pager: '#pager',
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    sortname: 'id', // NOT 'jobno' or 'Job Number'
                    sortorder: 'desc',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: 'Work Orders',
                    width: 950,
                    onSelectRow: function (id) {
                        //var d;
                        if (id) {
                            alert(id);
                            //??? onclick = openbox('Edit Work Order', 1);
                            //??? d = "jobno=" + id;
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'fillwo.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {jobno:id},
                                success: function (data) {
                                    var id;
                                    for (id in data) {
                                        if (data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                                            $(id).val(data[id]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            $("button, input:submit").button();
                        }
                        jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
                    }
                });
                jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
                initGrids[ui.index] = true;
            }
            else if (ui.index === 2) {
                alert('tab2');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I included array `initGrids` which will be used to initialize every grid only once, commented unclear code like `onclick = openbox('Edit Work Order', 1);` and fixed `sortname`.

You can see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/gridInTabs.htm). The grid contain will be not filled, because I not have any server components on the server

Comment: Proper!  You've been a great help.  I did have to change the sortname values back to the column names or else i got a mySQL error unknown column 'id'.  The onclick event pops up a light box that allows admins to edit the work orders or items.  I tried to work it back in to your example but nothing happens onclick.  I need to have this functionality.  Any more fantastic ideas?  Again thanks a million for the help!

Comment: Got it!  I had to include some html specific to the lightbox implementation i was using and it spins like a top!  Oleg I owe you a beer!

Comment: @Bill: If you use on the server another names as 'names' in the `colModel` you should use `index` property of `colModel` for this. Then if the user click on the column the value of the `index` property will be used as `sortname` or `sidx` on the server.

Comment: That just makes sense.  Again thanks for all your help.  Really spectacular.  And I'm serious about that beer.  You have a Paypal?

Comment: @Bill: You are welcome! I use PayPal of course at my private email oleg.kiriljuk@googlemail.com, but it would be enough if you just drink beer for me. I am glad to hear, that I could help you.

Comment: @Oleg: One more question for you.  I have a form that uses autocomplete and onblur to ajax in some user data based on first and last name.  it is in tab indexed2  do i cut and paste my script code into the else if ui.index ==2 area?  This doesn't seem to work.  I find when I comment out my first tab, the autocomplete works on tab3.  Can this be conflicting div ids or???  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: @Bill: What exactly not work in your code with the ajax? Do you debugged it with Developer Tools of IE of some other tool? In general id conflict of some other place where jqGrid generate HTML code fragments dynamically can has bug. To verify this you can try to place the jqGrid in the last tab. If all together work than it can be that jqGrid insert some open tag without the corresponding close tag (like `<div>` without `</div>`) and it follows to the problem. Having full code which could reproduce the described problem could probably help to say more.

Comment: So interesting.  I moved the 'gridded' tab after the ajaxed tab and all is well.  Weird nuances that I will research on a day when I don't have a deadline!  Thanks again!

Comment: @Bill: You are welcome! It means that jqGrid has bug in the dynamically generated code. The bugs can be like some old bugs described here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/few-bugs-in-3-8-in-xhtml-mode/. If you find some new bugs, let me knows about this and post it to http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/, so that Tony (the developer of jqGrid) can fix it in the main code of jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg i have posted a question for you which is based on your solution , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502312/multiple-jqgrid-inside-jqueryui-tab-v-1-10-3-very-strange-issue please help me thanks

Comment: @Mihir: Sorry, but your code is so terribly formatted, that one can't read it. The formatting is described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) for example. Moreover you don't need post all your current code. You can reduce the code so that all unneeded fragments are removed and the described effect (the problem) still exist.

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old question. But I also faced the same issue where in I had multiple jqGrids under the tabs and the loading thing was not working.
Adding the below code in the javascript just before defining the grid worked for me:

```
$('#Grid').jqGrid('GridDestroy');
```

For me, the grids on different tabs where the same only the data inside the grid was changing.