# Multiple jQgrids WITH filtertoolbar in jqueryUI Tabs do NOT work

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jqgrid

I have created multiple jQGrids on the same page using jqueryUI tabs.  The data loads fine on both tabs (click on tab 2 first - since i'm not loading data on page load initially).

Anyway, to recreate the problem I am experiencing download the code below (or browse to the jsfiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/ut5aE/) and do the following:
1.) Click on "Tab 2"
2.) Click on any search operation ("==") and notice that the other list of search operations come up.
3.) Click on "Tab 1"
4.) Click on any search operation ("==") and notice that the other list of search operations come up.
5.) Click back on "Tab 2"
6.) Click on any search operation ("==") on any column EXCEPT for the 1st column ("serial").  Now the search operation window showing the other search operations does NOT pop up and I get the following javascript error in the file jquery.jqGrid.src.js:

> Line: 4156
>   Error: Unable to get property 'searchoptions' of undefined or null reference

This is the exact line of code the error is on (including screen shot taken while debugging):

[image]

What is strange is that the operations ONLY work for the columns that have the same NAMES across all tabs.  Notice that clicking on the search operation ("==") ONLY on the 1st column (e.g. "serial") will WORK on both tabs, no matter how often you switch between the tabs.  But the rest of the search options do not work on tab 2 when you click on them - you receive no popup listing the other search operations, and will get the JS error noted above.

Here is the complete working code to test this issue:
The equivalent jsFiddle code can be found here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ut5aE/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Demonstration how to mark some cells as non-editable based on grid content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var initGrids = [false, false];
            $('#tabs').tabs({
                activate: function (event, ui) {
                    if  (ui.newTab.index() == 0 && initGrids[ui.newTab.index()] == false) {
                        var mydata = [
                                { id: "1", type: "2007-10-01", origin: "test", subtype: "note", refreshdate: "200.00" }
                                ];
                        jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
                            data: mydata,
                            datatype: 'local',
                            mtype: 'GET',
                            colNames: ['serial', 'type', 'origin', 'subtype', 'refreshdate'],
                            colModel: [
                                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55, sorttype: 'integer', search:true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'type', index: 'type', width: 90, sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'origin', index: 'origin', width: 80, align: 'right', sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'subtype', index: 'subtype', width: 80, align: 'right', sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'refreshdate', index: 'refreshdate', width: 80, align: 'right', sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } }
                            ],
                            pager: '#pager1',
                            rowNum: 10,
                            rowlist: [10, 20, 30],
                            sortname: 'id', // NOT 'serial',
                            sortorder: 'desc',
                            viewrecords: true,
                            searchOperators: true,
                            caption: 'CPE Items',
                            width: 950
                        });
                        jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: true, stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
                        initGrids[ui.newTab.index()] = true;
                    }
                    else if (ui.newTab.index() == 1 && initGrids[ui.newTab.index()] == false) {
                        var mydata = [
                                { id: "1", Date: "2007-10-01", System: "test", Status: "note", Technician: "200.00", Timeframe: "3" }
                        ];
                        $("#list").jqGrid({
                            data:  mydata,
                            datatype: 'local',
                            mtype: 'GET',
                            colNames: ['serial', 'Date', 'System', 'Status', 'Technician', 'Timeframe'],
                            colModel: [
                                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 75, sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'Date', index: 'date', width: 90, sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'System', index: 'wsystem', width: 80, align: 'right', sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'Status', index: 'status', width: 80, align: 'right', sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'Technician', index: 'wname', width: 80, align: 'right', sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } },
                                { name: 'Timeframe', index: 'time', width: 80, align: 'right', sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'ge', 'gt', 'le', 'lt'] } }
                            ],
                            pager: '#pager',
                            rowNum: 10,
                            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                            sortname: 'id', // NOT 'jobno' or 'Job Number'
                            sortorder: 'desc',
                            viewrecords: true,
                            searchOperators: true,
                            caption: 'Work Orders',
                            width: 950,
                            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                                //var d;
                                if (id) {
                                    alert(id);
                                    //??? onclick = openbox('Edit Work Order', 1);
                                    //??? d = "jobno=" + id;
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: 'fillwo.php',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        data: { jobno: id },
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            var id;
                                            for (id in data) {
                                                if (data.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                                                    $(id).val(data[id]);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    $("button, input:submit").button();
                                }
                                jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
                            }
                        });
                        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: true, stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
                        initGrids[ui.newTab.index()] = true;
                    }
                    else if (ui.newTab.index() === 2) {
                        alert('tab2');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
       <table id="list1"><tr><td/></tr></table>
       <div id="pager1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
       <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table>
       <div id="pager"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Bla bla</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code is a modified version from the post:
[Multiple jQgrids in jQueryui Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094259/multiple-jqgrids-in-jqueryui-tabs)

It includes the latest version of JQgrid and a more recent jQuery UI.
That stackoverflow posting did not use the "filterToolbar", and my problem pertains specifically to its flaw noted above in this question.  The above code snippet also loads a row of sample data.

Does anyone have a solution to this or is this a bug in jQgrid?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/multiple-jqgrids-with-filtertoolbar-in-jqueryui-tabs-causes-javascript-errors/

> I think I've worked out the cause of this issue.
>
> Find the following in the code:
>
> ```
> $(".soptclass").click(function(e){
> ```
>
> **Replace it with:**
>
> ```
> $($t.grid.hDiv).find(".soptclass").click(function(e){
> ```
>
> After a fair bit of investigation it appears that the click function
>   is applied to all grids that currently exist, this results in only the
>   last grid working correctly;  by changing the code that defines the
>   click event and restricting it to only the one table it will work
>   correctly.